# DLE CMS news raiting function didnt works

Tags: javascript, ajax, content-management-system

I stared do template on DLE CMS. I do that first time but it looks pretty easy. Now i have a trouble. I turned on standart rating system from DLE CMS into file **fullstory.tpl** (standard single news page). Design looks well, but if i try to click some stars to rate news, i get error "**Uncaught ReferenceError: doRate is not defined**" into my console. I understand that i dont have this function doRate on this page. But how to make it work fine? I found this function in other teplate into **dle_js.js** file. What this file mean and how i must to add it into my template. Thanks!

Comment: resolved: Standard files that must be included in each DLE CMS template:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/engine/classes/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/engine/classes/js/jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/engine/classes/js/dle_js.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi, You can use standard tag to include automatic this scripts in page, just use {AJAX} in your 'main.tpl' file. Regards.